# Directory Mapout is not working (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file

Note: *This question is  a bit long and only for people with some experience on batch. If you are willing to take some time on this question, analyzing it's bits of that and this, I'd be more than happy to comply.*

Hello guys, It's me again. This is based of my last question "Findstr to a variable w/ File count and subdirectories".

The program is a "File Searcher." THe DIR Command will output into a TEXT file, AND a FINDSTR command WILL find a certain string that matches your search term. If that is so, It's just like finding a file. As of now, Everything is in perfect working condition. The code is not yet done,  however the display of the directory "map-out" (The dir to a text file) is not working.

here's the code. (more text below the code)

```
@echo off
if NOT exist temporary goto make
:cont
set odir=%dir%
cd temporary\cache
if NOT exist partitionmapout.rsm goto partitionmapoutreq
goto cont2
:partitionmapoutreq
echo Note:
echo Would you like to Map out your whole C:\ Partition? This makes the program map out every single file in your C:\ Drive.
echo This can take from a few seconds to a few minutes (Depends on how much stuff you store in your drive)
set /p parch="Y/N: "
if %parch% == Y goto partitionmapout
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER (Copyright 2013 by Sonorous)
:cont2
cd temporary
set odir=%dir%
set /p cdir="DIRECTORY: " 
set domap=%cdir%
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER: Mapping out...
echo PLEASE WAIT, MAPPING OUT DIRECTORY.
dir %domap% /a-d /b /s > "tempres.rsm"
echo Directory Mapout done
echo -----------------------------
echo       DIRECTORY MAPOUT
set dirmapout=<tempres.rsm
echo %dirmapout%
echo -----------------------------
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER: Mapout done.
set /p "searchinput=Search Term: "
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER (Copyright 2013 by Sonorous)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /L /c:"%searchinput%" "tempres.rsm" ') do set "found=%%a"
set proin=%found%
echo "%found%"
cd temporary
del "tempres.rsm"
echo Would you like to open the program or just leave it alone? (Y/N)
echo WE CANNOT OPEN PROGRAMS W/ NO SPACES ON THEIR NAME.
set /p oc=""
if %oc% == Y goto openpro
pause
cls
echo THANK YOU FOR USING OUR PROGRAM. 
echo CLOSING IN 5 SECONDS
timeout /t 1 >nul
cls
echo THANK YOU FOR USING OUR PROGRAM. 
echo CLOSING IN 4 SECONDS
timeout /t 1 >nul
cls
echo THANK YOU FOR USING OUR PROGRAM. 
echo CLOSING IN 3 SECONDS
timeout /t 1 >nul
cls
echo THANK YOU FOR USING OUR PROGRAM. 
echo CLOSING IN 2 SECONDS
timeout /t 1 >nul
cls
echo THANK YOU FOR USING OUR PROGRAM. 
echo CLOSING IN 1 SECONDS
timeout /t 1 >nul
cls
exit

:openpro
echo NOTE: WE DO NOT KNOW THE PROGRAM'S FILE DIRECTORY, SO WE WILL START THE PROGRAM
echo THRU THE FILE DIRECTORY YOU INPUTTED.
pause
start %proin% 
exit

:make
echo Temporary Folder (Where the program stores temporary files)
echo Does not exist. Creating...
md temporary
cd temporary
md cache
cd %odir%
echo Complete.
goto cont

:partitionmapout
title Partition Map out...
echo Mapping out...
echo DO NOT CLOSE THE PROGRAM WHILE IT IS MAPPING OUT OR ELSE IT WILL FATALLY CRASH NEXT TIME YOU OPEN IT
echo The partition map-out is not done. Wait for a few minutes.
dir C:\ /a-d /b /s > "tempres.rsm"
echo The partition map-out is complete.
goto cont
```

The SPECIFIC area of the code which DOES NOT work is this;

```
cd temporary
    set odir=%dir%
    set /p cdir="DIRECTORY: " 
    set domap=%cdir%
    title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER: Mapping out...
    echo PLEASE WAIT, MAPPING OUT DIRECTORY.
    dir %domap% /a-d /b /s > "tempres.rsm"
    echo Directory Mapout done
    echo -----------------------------
    echo       DIRECTORY MAPOUT
    set dirmapout=<tempres.rsm
    echo %dirmapout%
    echo -----------------------------
    title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER: Mapout done.
```

The "dir" command is done mapping out the specified directory. Another command copies the output of the dir command to a variable. that variable has been set to display in the "DIRECTORY MAPOUT" part. however, it says

```
ECHO IS OFF
```

The "tempres.rsm" (The file where the directory mapout is stored) is in the "temporary" directory (as seen in the first line of the NOT working code EG. "cd temporary)
there is NO OTHER "CD" command, so it is assured that it is still in the same directory.

but when a variable is set to grab the data from "tempres.rsm", the data instead, is

```
ECHO IS OFF
```

**I hope i have provided you all enough details.**
*If not, make a comment and i'll sort it out for you.*

Comment: I've posted an answer, but in the future please limit your code to the portion relevant to what you're asking, and then *ask a specific question*. "Directory mapout is not working" is not a question, and having to wade through dozens of lines of code and text to find you didn't actually ask anything is somewhat annoying. :-) In this case, the relevant part of the code is just the last block that you marked as "THE SPECIFIC AREA" - the rest is just clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
dir "%domap%" /a-d /b /s > "tempres.rsm"
echo Directory Mapout done
echo -----------------------------
echo       DIRECTORY MAPOUT
type "tempres.rsm"
echo -----------------------------
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER: Mapout done.
```

I did not look at *all* code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
set dirmapout=<tempres.rsm
```

The `SET` command does not accept the redirection operator (`<`). If you open a command prompt to the folder where `tempres.rsm` is located and type

```
C:\Somedir>set something=<tempres.rsm
```

and then

```
c:\Somedir>set something
```

you'll see that `something` is not defined. Therefore, your `echo %dirmapout` is resulting in simply

```
echo
```

The result of `echo` on a line by itself is the current setting for `echo`, and in this case `echo is off` is the correct result.

Comment: The way to correct this is to escape the `<` with a `^`.  This is use `set dirmapout=^<tempres.rsm`

Comment: @shf301: That results in `dirmapout=<tempres.rsm`, which I don't think is the desired outcome. The poster is asking for the *content* of `tempres.rsm` AFAICT, not the filename.

Comment: to set a variable from a textfile, use `set /p dirmapout=<tempres.rsm` Btw: this may get a really huge tempres.rsm. I can imagine, that there is a length restriction of variables... You should better use Endoros suggestion.