# 'findstr' with multiple search results (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file

This is based on my last question's script:, [Directory mapout is not working (BATCH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028326/directory-mapout-is-not-working-batch/18029651?noredirect=1#18029651)

(For the whole script, click the link. However, you may only click the link if the following snip of code from "*directory mapout is not working*" does not really make sense to you)

```
<code>
cd temporary
set odir=%dir%
set /p cdir="DIRECTORY: " 
set domap=%cdir%
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER: Mapping out...
echo PLEASE WAIT, MAPPING OUT DIRECTORY.
dir %domap% /a-d /b /s > "tempres.rsm"
echo Directory Mapout done
echo -----------------------------
echo       DIRECTORY MAPOUT
set dirmapout=<tempres.rsm
echo %dirmapout%
echo -----------------------------
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER: Mapout done.
set /p "searchinput=Search Term: "
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER (Copyright 2013 by Sonorous)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /i /L /c:"%searchinput%" "tempres.rsm" ') do set "found=%%a"
set proin=%found%
echo "%found%"
cd temporary
del "tempres.rsm"
</code>
```

I want the "for /f" command to output MANY search results from one search term.
*Is the code not correctly formatted? Please message / comment on this question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to display the matching lines, then ditch the FOR /F altogether

```
title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER (Copyright 2013 by Sonorous)
findstr /i /L /c:"%searchinput%" "tempres.rsm"
cd temporary
del "tempres.rsm"
```

If you need an "array" of matching lines, then:

```
:: Define the array of matching lines
set "foundCount=0"
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ('findstr /i /L /c:"%searchinput%" "tempres.rsm" ') do (
  set /a "foundCount+=1"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%N in (!foundCount!) do (
    endlocal
    set "found%%N=%%a"
  )
)

:: Display the array values
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 %foundCount%) do echo match %%N = !found%%N!
```

Comment: `title SONOROUS FILE SEARCHER (Copyright 2013 by Sonorous & dbenham)` <-- will need to change this line. :)

Comment: I will change the line :D

Comment: Wait wait wait wait... So, If I use the first step, how can i output the results to a variable?

Comment: @BenedictRocat - I'm not sure what you mean by first step. The first code is only if you don't need any variables. The second code can be used if you do need variables.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I added your name and foxidrive's name to the copyright notes :D